# @font not working from fontsquirrel

Tags: css, html, font-face

I'm trying to use this font: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontfacedemo/eb-garamond
So I download the type kit and placed it in the correct directory.

**CSS**:

`@font-face {`

```
font-family: 'EBGaramondSC';
src: url('/EBGaramondSC-webfont.eot');
src: url('/EBGaramondSC-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('/EBGaramondSC-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('/EBGaramondSC-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('/EBGaramondSC-webfont.svg#EBGaramondRegular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}

p.style2 {font: 18px/27px 'EBGaramondSC', Arial, sans-serif;}
```

**HTML**:

`[p class="style2"]
Alfab Solutions, LLC is a custom security firm who focuses on rural secruity solutions.  We offer rugged, secure camera systems which integrate into our SSL encrypted website.  We provide 24/7 access to your security footage, so you can have peace of mind that your assets are safe.
[/p] Ignore brackets`

Firebug doesn't even show the correct font image.  What gives?
I have a weird directory structure.  The index is .php and it is generated from a template file.  So my fonts are in the template directory as they should be since they only affect the html there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the CSS code, you will notice that the url are all absolute paths (do you know about relative and absolute paths? If not, read about them :D )

```
@font-face {
   src: url('/EBGaramondSC-webfont.eot');
}
```

Notice the `/`?

It should be:

```
src: url('/templates/EBGaramondSC-webfont.eot');
```

Or, if the font files are in the same folder as the CSS:

```
src: url('EBGaramondSC-webfont.eot');
```

Opening the Chrome Inspector (That outputs 404 warnings) tells me that:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found) http://www.alfabsolutions.com/EBGaramondSC-webfont.svg

So yeah, that! Good luck.

Comment: Seems like that did it.  I'm not familiar with Chrome Inspector, but I'll look at it.  Firebug didn't show me the warning. I figured since the template was being served from that directory the fonts needed to be there as well.  Thanks for solving it.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your site and code, it is trying to load the fonts from /. Try changing the paths in the @font-face declarations to /template/* and see if it works.

Regards,
Raj

Answer (score 0):

You will only need to change your CSS file, `style.css`, such that the `src` attributes point to the correct paths for each font file:

**Incorrect**

```
src: url('/EBGaramondSC-webfont.eot');
```

**Corrected**

```
src: url('/templates/EBGaramondSC-webfont.eot');
```